# Set radio buttons using Jquery and html

Tags: jquery, html

My Jquery code is as follows

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload=function(){
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio][name=name]').change(function() {
        if (this.value == 'value1') {
            $("#myModal1").modal('show');
        }
        else if(this.value == 'value2') {
            $("#myModal2").modal('show');
        }
});
});
}
</script>
```

my html code is here,

```
<input type="radio" name="name" value="value1">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="name" value="value2">Femal<br>
```

and myModal1 is here

```
<div id="myModal1" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Male</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox">Amal
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox">kamal
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox">Nimal
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What I want to do is to set radio buttons like below,
if I click on "male" radio button then myModel1 should be appeared, and if I click on "female" radio button then myModel2 should be appeared. And both radio buttons should be selected. But I am unable to do that because I am a very beginner to jquery.
 If I want to select only one radio button and to get its modal, this code really works.
Could anyone please help me to set the code as what I need?

Comment: if you want both of radio button to be selected then remove the name attribute or set different name attribute to both.

Comment: try using this `$('input[type=radio][name=name]').change(function() {
 $(this).is(':checked') {
  if (this.value == 'value1') {
   $("#myModal1").modal('show');
  } else if (this.value == 'value2') {
   $("#myModal2").modal('show');
  }
 }
});`

Comment: @AshishJindal yeh, that is right. I can set different name attributes.But Could you help me to set my Jquery code?

Comment: You need to test the `checked` property, like `this.checked && this.value == 'value1'`

Comment: @Satpal thanks your comment.It helped me

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons are meant for mutually exclusive choices - not to be selected at the same time (use checkboxes for that):

also you can simplify your logic a bit:
set the value to either 1 or 2 for the radio buttons - on the change event - grab the value from the radio buttons and use that as a variable to trigger the modal to show.

Note that I am just consol.logging the changed value and have commented out the actual .'show') command since I don't have the modal in therte - but you would be able to apply this to your code and trigger the required modal.

I would also suggest only having the one modal and swap the display of different divbs within it to display the two states. Better than replicating the code for two modals.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=radio][name=name]').change(function() {
        var option =$(this).val();
      console.log('modal ' + option +' would be triggered');
      //$("#myModal" + option).modal('show');
       })
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="name" value="1"/>Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="name" value="2"/>Female<br>
```

Comment: By your answer I understood difference between radio buttons and checkboxes. Is it better if I use checkboxes instead of radio buttons?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `checked` property and display the model only for the radio button which is `checked`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=radio][name=name]').change(function() {
    //if the checkbox is not checked do nothing
    if(!this.checked)
      return;
    
    if (this.value == 'value1') {
      console.log('Show model 1')
    } else if (this.value == 'value2') {
      console.log('Show model 2')
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="name" value="value1">Male
<br>
<input type="radio" name="name" value="value2">Femal
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" onchange="fun(this);" name="name" value="value1">Male<br>
<input type="radio" onchange="fun(this);" name="name" value="value2">Femal<br>

<script>

    fun(this)
    {

    if(this.value=="value1")
    {
    $("#myModal1").modal('show');
    $("#myModal2").modal('hide');
    }else{
    $("#myModal2").modal('show');
    $("#myModal1").modal('hide');
    }

    }


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

first make you radio required like this

```
<input type="radio" name="name" value="value1" required>Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="name" value="value2">Femal<br>
```

then your jquery code to show the selected radio and hide the others like this

```
window.onload=function(){
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input[type=radio][name=name]').change(function() {
    if (this.value == 'value1') {
        $("#myModal1").show();
        $("#myModal2").hide();
    }
    else if(this.value == 'value2') {
        $("#myModal2").show();
        $("#myModal1").hide();
    }
 });
 });
 }
```